# update Twitter with tmhOAuth

Tags: php, twitter

I want to update my Twitter.  I  use tmhOAuth from themattharris . I have enabled Curl and  the Twitter app settings are correct with read write access. I checked the header and requests are empty. At first the code should work just changing the key and changes in Twitter. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

```
require 'tmhOAuth.php';
require 'tmhUtilities.php';
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
 // 'consumer_key'    => 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
  //'consumer_secret' => 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
  //'user_token'      => 'A_USER_TOKEN',
 // 'user_secret'     => 'A_USER_SECRET',
        'consumer_key'               => 's8wEiEo0EFk7fCX5jHfVfw',
        'consumer_secret'            => 'db2qENrjCRxtaOFs9a7wT7YPjWNRxO1yHHxT9EkM',
        'user_token'                 => '92957047-suEq4sH6ADTFXfOqrWfpbX6D9OqYGMyKA8CMAQVz4',
        'user_secret'                => 'LqhbQRp29M7L5UfdtJhde3kHxzB5oOn5xtGIdy35bOY',
));

$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1/statuses/update'), array(
  'status' => 'My Twitter Message'
));

if ($code == 200) {
  tmhUtilities::pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
} else {
  tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? You can follow this tutorial - http://bit.ly/136aL2M. Though the tutorial is for Yii, it can be easily followed for core PHP or any other framework.